# Python display Activate Configuration description with ASCII data

Tags: python

I am trying to convert the hex data to ASCII and then display the ASCII data with list Name followed by ASCII data.

If `response = ''` display `no data` and if `response = 'Hex data'`, convert it into ASCII data.I have written the code, but not able to get expected output.

My Code is as below:

```
data =    [{ "Name":"Activate1 Configuration No.:\t", "response":''},   
           { "Name":"Activate2 Configuration No.:\t","response":'62 F1 8C 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 31 35 36 38 36 38 31'},         
           { "Name":"Activate3 Configuration No.:\t","response":''}]


def function(ASCII):
  if(ASCII == 1):
    BResponse = response.replace(' ','')
    BResponse = BResponse.decode('hex')
    BResponse = BResponse[3:]
    print('response' + response)
    print ('ASCII' + BResponse)
  else:
    print('response' + response)

for readdta in data:
  temp_text = '{0}'.format(readdta['Name'])
  response = '{0}'.format(readdta['response'])
  if(function(1)):
     if(response == ''):
        print 'No data'
     else:
        print 'temp_text   '+ BResponse
```

I am expecting output as follows:

```
Activate1 Configuration No.: No data
Activate2 Configuration No.: 0000000011568681 (ASCII Data)
Activate3 Configuration No.: No data
```

Comment: Your code *explicitly* prints `Hello` and `temp_text`, which isn't in your expected output, which makes me question your expectation.

Comment: @ScottHunter...I have edited the code. Make this question as clear. If it goes to negative, no one will answer it. I have show most of relevant questions are not answer because of this.

Comment: Maybe you should explain why your expected output is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly manipulate the data, no need to use a function, like this:

```
data =    [{ "Name":"Activate1 Configuration No.:\t", "response":''},   
           { "Name":"Activate2 Configuration No.:\t","response":'62 F1 8C 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 31 35 36 38 36 38 31'},         
           { "Name":"Activate3 Configuration No.:\t","response":''}]

for readdta in data: #for loop all the data
    temp_text = '{0}'.format(readdta['Name']) #get the value of Name
    response = '{0}'.format(readdta['response']).replace(' ','') #get the value of response
    if response == "":
        response = 'No data'
    else:
        response = response.decode('hex')[3:] #decode the response
    print temp_text + response #print them out
```

Output:

```
Activate1 Configuration No.:    No data
Activate2 Configuration No.:    0000000011568681
Activate3 Configuration No.:    No data
```

Answer (score 1):

`function` doesn't return anything, so `if function(1)` always fails, and thus you never get any of your expected output (though you get a bunch of, apparently, unexpected output).